# Uniform convergence for sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Is $f_n(t)$ uniform convergent in $(0,\infty)$ for $$f_n(t)=\frac{\sin(nt)}{n\sqrt t}?$$
I tried and proved it when $t\ge1$, but got confused when it comes to $0$.

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff I prove it for $t\ge 1$,but have no idea with $0$.

Comment: What does the function converge to pointwise on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff For $lim_{n->\infty}f_n(t)=0$

Answer (score 1):

The pointwise limit is the zero function.

To show uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$, here is an outline (as a "Hint" for how to deal with things near $0$, just look at the first bullet point):

- Note that for $t>0$
  $$|f_n(t)|=\biggl|\sqrt{t} \cdot{\sin(nt)\over nt}\biggr|\le\sqrt t.\tag{1}$$
- Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $N$ so that $1/N <\epsilon^2$.
- Use the given definition of the $f_n$  to show that this selection "works" for $t\ge\epsilon^2$ and $(1)$ to show it "works" for $0<t <\epsilon^2$.